# Angular 8 make football match using JSON

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular8, ngfor

i want to create football matches using this JSON:

```
export const teams: Array<any> = [
  {
    name: 'A',
    teams: [
      {
        name: 'France',
      },
      {
        name: 'Portugual',
      },
      {
        name: 'india',
      },
      {
        name: 'china',
     }
    ]
  },
]
```

so for example i want to make matches france vs india than france vs china .

so i am using Angular 8 , and i have some issues if anyone can help me in that code .

HTML:

```
<div class="col-3" *ngFor="let group of group1">
    <h5>{{ group }}</h5>
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
this.group1 = this.teams;

this.teams.forEach((item, index) => {
    this.groupList.push(item.name);
    item.teams.forEach((item, index) => {
        this.group1.push(item.name);
    });
});
```

Comment: what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: i want to make football matches for this group . like make france vs india than china and etc..., i dont know how to make it

Comment: over here you are suppose to post technical difficulty that ur facing with the specific steps. It is still not clear to me

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you want to do is display a list of all possible matches within this JSON, and I assume that since the teams array is in it's own array of objects with a name tag, that there may be separate groups of matches that you wish to display.

I have created a Stackblitz project you can view [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-make-football-match-using-json-answer?embed=1&file=src/app/components/my-component/my-component.component.html) to see my implementation of what I believe it is you are looking for.

I will explain my code below.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-3" *ngFor="let group of groupList">
     <h5>{{ group }}</h5>
</div>
```

I wasn't sure what the difference between 'group1' and 'groupList' were supposed to be in your code, so I have selected groupList as my display value, and use 'group1' as a property in the TS.

TS:

```
for (let teamGroup of this.group1) {
  this.groupList.push("Group: " + teamGroup.name); // show the group
  for (let team1 of teamGroup.teams) {
    for (let team2 of teamGroup.teams) {
      // iterate over every possibility of two teams facing each other
      if (
        this.groupList.indexOf(
          String(team1.name + " vs. " + team2.name)
        ) === -1 &&
        this.groupList.indexOf(
          String(team2.name + " vs. " + team1.name)
        ) === -1
      ) {
        // filter out matchups already pushed to the array
        if (team1.name !== team2.name) {
          // filter out self-matches
          this.groupList.push(team1.name + " vs. " + team2.name);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the Stackblitz implementation, I'm using 'teams' as a property of my component, assigned to the JSON you provided, but you can get this JSON dynamically and use this code, just make sure to assign the value to the 'group1' property.

The 'groupList' property is an empty array, which we will .push() the values we wish to display to. By looping over the 'teams' array within the first (and only) entry in your JSON, we can decide on a display format for the string (I have chosen 'Team1 vs. Team2') and compare all possible matchups between two teams within the group against entries in 'groupList'. If the matchup does not exist, we will push the matchup to 'groupList'.

The end result is this:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daIti.png)

I hope this was what you were looking for. I would have asked a clarifying question in the comments first, but I'm too new to the website to be able to.